# Suddenly can't Remote Desktop into Win2k3sp2 server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I went and upgraded our domain functional level to Windows Server 2003, then rebooted.  Now I can't log in via remote desktop from any of the following clients:

1. Haiku (rdesktop)
2. Linux (KRDC)
3. WinXP SP3

   1. on network

      1. built-in version
   2. off network

      1. built-in version
      2. [Remote Desktop Connection 7.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084)
4. Windows 7

However, regular authentication (i.e., not over remote desktop) from WinXP SP3 clients on the network works fine.  Off-network, I can connect to the same server on other ports for other services no problem, and I haven't changed any port-related settings lately.

The error message, which appears almost immediately after clicking, is:

```
---------------------------
Remote Desktop Connection
---------------------------
This computer can't connect to the remote computer.

Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner
of the remote computer or your network administrator.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

The client is set to "warn me" for auth and "auto" for gateway.

I've tried with and without the console switch.

Apparently, [raising the DFL doesn't necessarily break RDP](https://serverfault.com/questions/207468/can-raising-the-domain-function-level-to-windows-server-2003-cause-remote-deskt).  So I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.  I've never had it break this way before, and raising the DFL is the last thing I did before I rebooted, and the only configuration change I can remember making.

Given all the ways we *can* still access the server, and that otherwise it's functioning fine, how do I fix it so I can log in via remote desktop once again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restarting the remote desktop service.  If that doesn't fix it try rebooting again.  Sometimes the remote desktop service will not start correctly.

Comment: Yep, a simple reboot from the console fixed it.  And this time I clearly had no ability to change anything on the server in between.  Unbelievable.  Thanks!